# Enumerate the results retrieved from show tables

Tags: mysql

I retrieve all the tables within the current database

```
#+begin_src sql :engine mysql :dbuser org :database grocer
show tables;
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| Tables_in_grocer |
|------------------|
| Customers        |
| OrderItems       |
| Orders           |
| Products         |
| Vendors          |
```

How could enumerate them as:

```
#+RESULTS:
| No. | Tables_in_grocer |
|-----+------------------|
|   1 | Customers        |
|   2 | OrderItems       |
|   3 | Orders           |
|   4 | Products         |
|   5 | Vendors          |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) (MySQL 8.0+) and select all tables from [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/tables-table.html):

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TABLE_NAME ASC) AS `No.`, TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE IN ('BASE TABLE', 'VIEW')
  AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'grocer'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME ASC
```

In case you are using MySQL < 8.0 (without support for window functions) you can use the following:

```
SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number+1) AS `No.`, TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES, (SELECT @row_number:=0) rn
WHERE TABLE_TYPE IN ('BASE TABLE', 'VIEW')
  AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'grocer'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME ASC
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2a48f864283169513b9e44bde40e8124)

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
  select @a:=@a+1 No, table_name
    from your_schema.tables
    (SELECT @a:= 0) AS a;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the dbname in the query so that table from particular database will show up. the above queries will show tables from complete information schema and can have some extra tables.

```
SELECT (@rNum:=@rNum+1) AS `No.`, TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES, (SELECT @rNum:=0) rn
WHERE (TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' OR TABLE_TYPE = 'VIEW') and  table_schema = 'DBNAME'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME ASC
```